# Calling an object from a class with Default Constructor

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I'm wondering what a call to an object is supposed to display. I have a class called big_number that has a few different constructors. In another method, I'm declaring an object 'a' using class big_number as follows:

```
big_number a;

cout << "Default constructor gives " << a << endl;
```

And my constructor is:

```
big_number::big_number()
{
    head_ptr = 0;
    tail_ptr = 0;
    positive = false;
    digits = 0;
    base = 10;
}
```

(Although I'm sure that this constructor is wrong).

The full code of the testing file:

```
    int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    unsigned int base;
    string s;

    char choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "Type 'd' to test default constructor" << endl;
        cout << "Type 'i' to test int constructor" << endl;
        cout << "Type 's' to test string constructor" << endl;
        cout << "Type 'a' to test assignment" << endl;
        cout << "Type '>' to test input operator" << endl;
        cout << "Type '=' to test comparison operators" << endl;
        cout << "Type 'q' to quit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        if (toupper(choice) == 'D')
        {
            big_number a;
            cout << "Default constructor gives " << a << endl;
        }
//More Code
```

Comment: What about the constructor do you think is wrong? Do you think printing out an arbitrary class is supposed to give you meaningful information? Well it isn't. You have to provide your own overload of the stream inserter for that syntax to work.

Comment: Did you overload the `<<` operator? Then when you do `<< a` it will print out whatever you wrote in your function. Also, could you post some more of the code? I can't really tell if the constructor is wrong or not just from that.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut I added the method calling big_number a.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't give us enough information. First try telling us what the actual *problem* is.

Comment: I'm trying to take a number in using different constructors that use ints, strings, deep copies of a doubly linked list with the goal of saving the digits as a doubly linked list that can change according to the base of the number system used. It's supposed rewrite different operators in terms of this list.


Atleast I think that's what I'm doing. My teacher didn't really explain what I'm supposed to be doing so well.

Comment: So you're basically trying to convert a number into a linked list, where each digit is a node?

Comment: @RockOnRockOut I would assume so.

Comment: @SoraMarch lol, what exactly does your assignment ask you to do? The title of this question doesn't imply that you would need to print your object. Are you confused on how to call a member function or something?

Comment: @RockOnRockOut I'm currently just trying to make sure that my default constructor is set up correctly so that it can set the values in the header file to 0. I need to just set up the default constructor.

Comment: Looks okay to me, but I can't tell precisely without seeing the code for the header file. Did you write the setters and getters? Use those to do some unit-testing.

Answer (score 1):

If by "call to an object" you mean your call of the `operator<<` on the object `a` with `cout` as the stream argument: It displays whatever you define it to display (in a member function of `big_number` or a free function). There is no "default" `operator<<` for user-defined classes. So, if you define it like

```
#include <iostream>

struct big_number
{
    template<typename T>
    friend T& operator<< (T& stream, const big_number& bn);
};

template<typename T>
T& operator<<(T& stream, const big_number& bn) {
    return (stream << "Hello World");
}

int main()
{
    big_number a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

... it will just display "Hello world".

The purpose of making it a `friend` function is so it can access the private data members of `big_number` (since you usually want it to display something that depends on the data stored in the object, and not a constant "Hello world"). So, within the `operator<<` definition, you would probably iterate through the digits in your linked list and push them to the stream (if I understand correctly what you are trying to do).